# Does ELL need new moderators?

Tags: discussion

I noted that Matt, WendiKidd and waiwai933 are substantially no longer active on ELL and its metasite.

Is this a circumstance which impedes to ELL to be graduated?

Also, does ELL need new active moderators?

Comment: Do you see any evidence that the moderators are not doing their job? --which is mostly activity which doesn't show up in posts or on their profiles.

Comment: It's true that there's moderator inactivity here, but that shouldn't affect the site's graduation prospects.  Part of the site graduating is electing moderators for the first time, which seems like it should solve any moderator inactivity problems, real or perceived.

Comment: The users that are best qualified to answer are the current active mods. They'll know if flags are piling up, and they can easily get new moderators appointed by writing a mail to SE, if necessary.

Comment: @StoneyB You can view a user's profile and see when they last visited, though what they did is not discernible. As of this writing, waiwai93 last visited December 15 and Wendikidd last visited December 18 (JR and Matt are active). One might argue that a week is too long for a moderator to be absent, which is possibly the reason for this post. I disagree with both that claim and the one that there's insufficient moderation here, but just saying...

Answer (score 11):

I don't see any issues with the current moderation. Every issue I've seen or flagged has been handled promptly. Maybe their moderation duties are what's keeping them too busy to be active as regular community members ;)

Because there are no obvious issues, I agree with @MadScientist that the current moderators are the ones that should make the call as to whether or not extra hands are needed.

Answer (score 3):

"It's true that there's moderator inactivity here, but that shouldn't affect the site's graduation prospects. Part of the site graduating is electing moderators for the first time, which seems like it should solve any moderator inactivity problems, real or perceived." 

—snailboat

Answer (score 3):

I, myself, am not a moderator, but I would imagine it's not an easy task. The moderators of ELL & ELU are at least civil, patient, & give their best effort to answer questions. Try this for a comparison. Ask a question on Stack Overflow. You'll get the moderators from Hell. It seems they spend more time negatively evaluating questions than they do answering them. Some of the SO moderators are helpful, but they are among the few. The ELL moderators do a far superior job.

Note: I upvoted this question, only to offset a downvote. Don't confuse Useful/Not Useful with Like/Dislike. In my observation, ELL & ELU moderators welcome criticism, both positive & negative. Though, I encourage all contributors to be positive in their participation.

Comment: I down voted not because I didn't like the question, but because it didn't have much detail. The question doesn't say what "substantially no longer active" means and why that might indicate we need new moderators. The question "does not show any research effort".

Comment: On a Meta site, upvoting/downvoting have different meaning than on the main site: usually an upvote is for "I agree with or support this idea/proposal" and a downvote is "I think this idea/proposal is unnecessary or inappropriate".

Answer (score -5):

There is troll activity and bullying on this site which is not being addressed.

I agree that there are far too many being allowed to evaluate commentators' responses instead of addressing the learners' questions. This site seems to have lost the point that it is for the learners - first and last.

Comment: Morag, please. The answers you made were flagged, and the moderation team took a look. **Patience**. The moderation team is not on duty 24/7.